# read.table return Inf with very large digits in a variable

Tags: r, read.table

I am using read.table to read my data, which has several rows and only column (or variable), however this variable contains about 47000 characters of 0,1,5.
R return `Inf` for all rows which I have not been able to figure out why?
Does anybody know what is the issue here?

A subset of first row of this data is below:

```
010150251152012012101201121025111005202021111115550501010020000550101002502520012011525021001110022502201220011051211200012110151555501150150000205151521552152125201115151520050255555102101555152522215005020511015255121511515522521010155501100020551552111522051502100020112100015050151252201150202005025252000511505125110022551105050501100555502015111505515151122121125102155152000505011510025055105515025551002505502552010150510021100100201012010501555210101550010502550550055155150121111500555512115550502252102551110211022100525020550552101551551505211511010051010111250550112251550121050001151111011555200525552101001215105110555550555520005110212552250225050255155555101512020255050515505051011021252512011500000221000150211201225512112511501021021025501505115555155001202500521002521020505511551255515120520551101151115021250005221155121202101255555102511200120101011521225100215522252021225012011250010222205515222122255011102552252105005252515510215121551155215025025551211120205555502010510255100552201215012551250501250511510055151111000211510215202025012002555001015005205102512211120102251221515055111221000015051200552552115101551102111002151100512550500252155001255222001525525550050100552152155015125055555550025212505251100520015202551011005015025051100010500555211512555051100522155500015151551005550015510115115155105020052021122201521011220120515511120025502505055520050105200521052125121222220201155012501551051215551525015500152250150505055512212111110010021201001051251251111125150115010500155010522021112250125005515055025105200520200112112050500522011552212251115110105125050015500220122121110111015501150201511021251202000121210550111015021010101250152105520000011021055005120155220252252522212010250100011501050155225115021012125120050525501015012005050151502251500201105525010015210100205102015102000150225125001211501225010501221052511115012000101125505020502100102222122552120102502112520555515051220250005101125201125211225115022500125011502115512011551515512005205010211555525011521202100550221522100000210101120201000252155551152005111515011102050201115011020525205521255020002125120015012021511115215151212121551151005121520012121111225015501102005050105101120200512512102520010102111050010201250501020515025501555550102115551000152552552215212511010555010122005051251520511011501052255110120102120220122105021015120021005001101002021252205122155000522105155010002151250110501001220551511005051010155502105150111015500202012122211551155125205100101110122122202515015505110550210100252055501201101555511000521125012050050501050215052551515511525011202551222222011101222502025110151121102201210512105502210120202012105055101550201220055552225521021101550025155111515102111151201125112215021020502011521505125115225500251110520551202250515002021121052010050155005115200012521505205251111125511105502012202122255151221252255122021515512111150250005121150251150010251210050110050212025002250251001551152000005211051052510105502051510000252200120110525102010021222050550512121552510002525112110100522551011110125111100000150052252150525502212052102221550551520051505010210250502011055255051002211055125500000115151520055505202252015212255051250101522025055050221055015111555105025002121105105151051010501522201122010122000102251111515155202010052521115521005222221110505515150511251211210215205505521550205151005112105015515511215551111552021521201021212511211501101001012011215252021500220555511112221055521220510250005502555155501201501220105050020551102052151201215005520500001210051252051200005112251515005505052010221550150010510121222205100211222002500555105550152110122251155051122505100512015221200055211012020011252222522101520021511501550211152121152510110115020010015502210150210105550155152111102255525105021520552112520205250500500010050002155505205510515252215051500125055010150015510011551021015001510051222111155152210210102102501152212501512205555225211515005515121122115555025051515050010105155212210200051505000055521022011152201010505025055201200200005522010110002025525121021500020001210211100112552010112020111112211115251212520515501521151001515550010111000102215050105515220225011100125121010520020505250001200220200150100100555251502151152011011501015010020021521150551152501051211255015520011221021112055550120002125005051025015120005501000101111115001005521555515510001022000520010151121502111152110005210155200100551515255250012512522521501055511050012155200250005102252220151502051250211021100052512100210051111100055211550220521100050115200115155505251550025052255255511120115110202055502515011000020110101500555110221515552500001100002501500012102110151105015551000211220011100505500501501552250110051211155100512155101051100101001151051521012025001100002155010112220250122025521215005020550021212050222121522101101155510025152112211505122205522212112550521051205511210021122252022050050201120500005120125011020500152221501215020501155052112001500525121551122502252122211110001550121225011120022100015002120001050120111001105015221102521000151222220522210500015510200022210220055512021122011021211155125025020122150525101500112000501110212521515010115110225010110105025125100512121111111110102202551100102201150251012012220012501515211200101210101200520005251215500050025210110151510051121111221015002212111011101011022211150211200152100122110552101111251011101122051111151111210522215011025215250552111050121201102101121201001001050015151510111105502100205211110101111200001052105110015150120101015255121111250052522510111000100120050222251252111120512510520512102101521221021022005555050210211011255551105021112102151502121512525505101505011550111125511511522020212222150122502551111051211210100510010002120201121510020152021020550015105510252501021051000501112021525025210251151550210200222502111101122512202100155051551515155012151021010120221122252022011205255505202205121501105102000250501120015511121115021101120250512101112011100501152151251102055112222011210125101015225220021102110120505050201012120525000100202101115502121250202210102020550015251202111222210252201205112222111111112100121150120100152505002100120152205151502101011110551112202222125221110500205211002151122101122100010520550521122111110112512112001001221021210512025000122222112120001552501152212111221210111112510550122511511150215500010501111250105212105150210111221111510520511000125015051100205110512011022010252011151520525511115021020122121252021525152500521552521110151502120012105212115102211225002052110555510112522521121102512211225001222210055002520251122112000205121200510202115200520221110125010002200105125101151225121001150115550521150151052025502100512500012012550012100125510220025152551111150551020100500015210101510010111251011125150012210002105021510151552510000510211001011510102515101010021210201011102015051515222105110125201051511152515505200500520002155101011200151021202155012015025111201252515155022012525150550125520205201200205552000510511110001021110211102111515021002551551050005221151215005012202110020111001000010201255221151210055011521511021122501201020220525000001101211102051150215000550520152100022555120121501521005102211022512021111251515010515111010052111501150000502021100021112100001101212011551211112001121025525200000512512005120011000512201002011101055120221510105001020122211201152510100512202002120520022252201255150122050211550101022022510051020250501115105110211052500111222505215101012021101010122220112522105121100251201100501251001511102001101220220211212102025020210112015102100211210001105051010020211101020120151105010510052551500211002215010012251200521011501212512101110505511201200121221115510102021502202122112511512200511222222101210201122501102111212122155551500201200152201125101551115050020120111005120510011155112125212021152221120210122012520151052502020001510510521015012005125520211125521250252215101211022050015155101222012522201111021115515012115120512005501011000500021201501050112011211501512211112110251501115520115511115500201521510122202101512511521020021252555551011505101101021501122010211510111055011250100112221525020005020520125011120020020251100111251022510011222110051020102022211001010001251112205111212001120151502102122205200101100201201110250110102022001011051251222501551515512102521502110021055000001251111001120001211110151111105052121522111100511111001050510505252510115201252021000000000115150012512502050221115101151001055012015150110015151102205121510221150010002251155021110015005011501010121111505020115211112551150520205200050100025051100111022005110101551115501155522120125152121001251125220510151022015201122021025100250505115120010102510255152010121512210501511050202201201110152101050555000512000102202000001501222121510200115025115205220051211111221515555001550151001010512552121225102005002101100152210522200022000005552500102515551102120005502215522005002151151111521200501011155220522225521525155550525505555255525050522552155225012555525550015105552505505225500015150555555550255525512155555515501552055155520255202555125002001055555502055151021015150550555525105121152501205225555115021010250105225552010551515555012211110225510110255555005521505505051051152555550521551555155555015055515255521552555555555555101555555551551121505255000215511255115550525555552521125055500151522552550515552525525055121555015525155155155551501205550555052155155555555150151525505205525555155551510111050125505155555502155251511215211052101010222050201002020150111525000511000252221055200052510011222515502255505250500055055252252201200005205025501055150551510211115250500011010250052155522021511012200050115002000502100111012505055521510501121012002150120010500121501525220555210205020111050005105050102250051121202122252020020020202101201112200000050522015051501055000202151101200050220251210552120121111521155001202125055501151251221100110120202215500150020105021010502111205250125115012112511011021125510125020155151210220011222511510520051211000051511102515221200112510100155551100110151520000115055001000011051122025000101115115511225012510122052050111125052052015005505525101152250055050500052011051020201100105015550022212505021020221205510550222200502550101511502552105211500505501105215552015212010105105252201550221210500255551110010525252505550550211505515005011522115055151125210215111522021220552511210051011520100052511525051552521515510002020050052220251551155251202211020550115120112521051502011500255251211051022215552551520001015525150225501525000122152501020515101002115105050501220115212010125551122201020515520120502010512502500151020551120110020550551011510121110215110550051050510225002021055552125510500255520251505501155255201150551552210550052110112210001150101050205120110125521150100110221010215501055521002512255515101112512000002152051122201551102115011215151511201021555120000100202015105120551555051505105500525205112222111220210012222551102151015200055100122111511152222522120151505152101521511520555252210515052250155512212202125111120201052552525025520122005155525150101510512220510112515002505555115255010025522021550025005205510511051551115152110201015201051155102551112151052022011120215125150012255011120505211211052152155100152505225000005152115012500150555152521021022210110225551550115005115050021215215151511205110111521022122122112010115110521201120515555125100150511520105215210252212111222220025251251105052500220251555550101050010050505100022151500001105010105511212251005011052015001150151550211110550550501115100010550502150200010205111112502001051552112151510200201021555501210011122110511005220225021001210152025150125155112055152510152155225511215515120120101110002215551150522210001001555551511210520222255520501202521025521500152551202122255511520151251011150112010500015505552552222102100155010002202521002252100011255510015500525100011251551005150102100051011505125002210055020510050050200550501500002221210021010105152005120222515555510001121101000050505215100205005555205555050111500005502201202505555215225500151150522515151010020215022100515122501155055500100550111055220015025125102105555100211125000551020050001105100052510010021105505505150125025550115512020510505551505525052025505515150110201515555010552505511155510050101011002100052005110005011022111015215152205100121151121520120200005125010211201005051000101550111022250112510510015105120520255000050101500115210200112012050152250255015555510005001500102115250225050525122520522105110005125011020122002221010255201012152022021221152105101002025001210002110105111020200511525101102525205005055010525112052515055220255021210215201015002510112105120000255150521112110111222551255050002005255210212520525151005252202205505155111102120105511555111211050150015055550121055515122510125222051251015255001151015150010220055150012501000512251105520511205002215201110000551221502021515205125200020111021550200525225155100251152011500210020001105550525500120250510255002522015025022110052215105012050221525015511051020211215050110155220001152110051020011102200200102101211515252005115015550121000005101111511121210500000111225500015205155011505202225250102055102211100250021155112001520115100510150251021211110151011211150155012201101520522100110000012052002050010502020001255215152101010100510051015220110522220011052552025122125515212110015110002121511020255225225215051050051501510155115025122501521000522125220250052002110051501110121212251525502101551255152015050512205120101001100055110010250550520202501015055052515000121210020211125025201250100100251000151551225110010552512105101510155121505555000100212055552212122150510025050121215105511105550102252201215050255521502221155500220010511205212020052505120021210501511552101000110051102212501520202001115100255120151120105502022010552001101205100521005215002011555511210115052210050015151205555551000505112500051220202505520512505112555011212551001201011521515011015001551550002505525122051152511515022221000002525550220505215002055112052501105505010550020120511512152515055100000552202550005101120101515510551525220051520100052521525210111212505515500201000551515120110502015255115110025555121521515255052015520125220155105225202500101510111222220055021201522555002510155055050015111515251202015100010152505005155521000020105510125512052552151025525000222110501551015001055005002055150000102020005110252151511155025215115151505512021115515051151150001000001005022525001020012010100211520500000051101102112510010552251221100102051115522021202155120551251155025502501051000500511101200201112501210515120151220512121120111110005552051525525051010055120505502550000510110105221505512511155100555155101010512020202225021000022221002252205501151105002210110550112255202255051110105115052001205052555001151011015052511021150255055212512210200100055510250521125205221515001021501521205221500011552110205111050022501505011012011100005501110202150515151052010205521111520101255200551120510052021110002021515052155001521052101252555022055022220110550122051251150011205021121202012101520055211025205025220521150050115250502001055221115501011001255155505015200100150151111102111015112215002001150101552151220510105152021201010022511011022520205105050112020552112555201215100001250012201512111111115500150025021015150151510502220225121020202200211150121510551025212010055051011050000100010002151505211252152005102210215002550151510052551011015111022215152225501110550152500121100210000022205000511055510122105011102115251552520255151550500215511055505125521152201552511201002220020000515102015125020552225010515125521155105211552005212105202155051555102155501551511100050115552015211110150000151022100052000525102201211510051211210515055100020025522520002201200200020552002100010120015250021212020112120550105055251251121150115151151055550521025201502551250221515202005100211505000015012051551011020102122511222211211150111220105502551101502102520002050100121150500125512025101121200210512002050150051102000512525015005101025115121100000250125115105021110505515051551211200155000115112510120551111551100200112210525055121550210501500001512225152212112255252005102025015555105120125510120500202010000002112521021200050511105025210525502052105502502515050021111550221201525112552520155105025155515255552025220552001011121000511105015011212555205021010221050111020225200500550520221150112512121510151121112050055110511120200515215000000522550100202015002211151155025212201012201005050110002055512051552155052112210502122220051111021515101210025552052101210521120000501515502525121510525511511500555055501220225052152221051252502001111201050202110211522101120051012120002201120210015220550521125120025020122501051201001002052500111155121510212550210110151015510511550115525111055505012055115121121011015501511501220520550551000520520001101552025110055211210000205021510155212112102022551222151200221512512155110221521055512205021551010155215001005001522051111112012500055511101205521125150101052511525251250005155125102100210111100002550205051015551511120510215022215201222501015100150015020020150112125220050015505512050122111010010052102215202200002101051155021120002100505052205011052100220011200010205150525200251511521002022122212125200522511205002120000021115111251100002520015002122102000520220015020200002050110501021110250012225221205055522002022525211201212001011501550110555221051250511555100002201100500550205121151111120120525552505122202111150500212215505220121100025222020212151051021521052550021521115011211555150115015021525105250005505110555101202001152111552255051105111512001001105150555550205100201000022020011505150010520511015150011100111512200221015210101525002512015500102025015522102211150005055521051105011510551552255100220250201510211155011202151100001510002200501522005521501210121002012521121105215552115055101501100210000010200025111510015015205510201005500012511155505000210220250100155525201210551511000251515025510205215151205000112101211500100005020522112052152220155155251011011121051121110010110122011152251152202500205510015020200022015202225521205225211115111055205115021025505552520550551001012110112555211515511005012201521510022522011515525025251211502555220121202225115210022020025111505102221112525005511051502005215021001200515225125110010101555001001101251552211512222105200010051501505211111551200050552110215102125021110225051115101000025105250051015555110001500011221150021110555201551025215525202100210011211152110252205222010021120220220112220505111150555501551122155552512021505555222000005015202155552125001151012022112511121050025122505005020501101125110212551005252012001515502015055015510051012052011020202111251021555055001121015052522201111550010252025055210511125012500150010105050525511100210011121110515211202051110011210550025021022015150202155250515020202101521505000211011015220205125501000012002555112011155121101120225050201055252115012522500121525121512051020112122011512112051225051120212551050205200505150155551012101000005012015100020251025115201155111550020151111502021215055125115555505101005012021100020550252015112120120521105552255550150055510005052111100205515000550251000055211121100511212555001520051000050225551202001000005052115552512551012001055202021021252505010111001105002115502020111052110251212051211111251252510211021515151151122551011210512021125051011011051251255500525121205102515102551100251115155522205521150015120512010551010505550155120151125501220105220115105050002500052100112055102025005010510105151150155552505015005505011555525511201020002000210511110100552152012021222212221002150020515151205121150001005505150525100015212511551520551202501520010120021151011050055100250150210150152210150010000012251122122550502525122025051221500551021100152011222022520151051250525125021550155100015001012211150550111115521555200555510255021505202252000152121512021101201111005052125005050510111005101200512022015020015100222105022522015105122211110100100255152512011025202250205225100551105550105501000205151100522020100021010250200211555211220502252055505221500550100501115052050520552115001250002050100502055151555010510505522020250120212105015050550022055122155201201252015510121221012111052121222505055125015051005025102020152510202210511500250151521151522005110055001001050011012510021000052515052125510252252051220102050522200201512251550511521125110152225001100050521121552501010101025021500115225255000525550525110020115011201210151155120552525250550101550520255252252021250005152100102550051500055221012125551105525122500220052552005221055111020200221512221001022120511152102052501520525500505502101000001101000551512201150020120550512025505110151011201010512105155015552152512520555255102510221121015025102255111051522501055522215050121511505252505022021101251522500512555110511210120121211515021102055202210025012150115211025500200502520551102102050011551200251250125551500221011125010005551021011225115105000251205151155552155512122005100000111215020011012215011152105101015005512052115005205150105200152102505510120111215125252012055510001225555115010551121225500002252511525052011101550215205215102010011101505515102212001201015221102501255525202510251550500200002555002100521112520205250001025111511222000250015051000102205125250101511505551105001021102501550550150125210150152250155200010505500511515555200025115220002505100505521150212005202125021210111200112505151022115051100050000501255152220220220015212220121252510151515010100102000225520015525222252555120110521015225515510225511152000151155120000251222052012520002021000551251552502152010012500005525002110100000500250120551050020115515510051002005255005112105055515250555550100225500051111520105225110051255050015151252515021055550150121152002102015550001211000020151010051221022550225120251102251105152001025521250500020510000502500212502100050225025200005525250110511125015011002512000115501012552505110002005101552150111050051551021055000201212251150011000005015515210212051011015022021511110011522205102255252215120010511055022055025512555220200551151121011011505011112155100111021511150052015120511001052002002210112021022112250555521101051121050502020015005201002155211005050010011025005052055052520121025101105121115025520101222252001515122501225125251000050200055251550002212552021110552555200155121500110522010501251500101200221501125515501021050101211025205005520115210000112525011121211112005005000510202111212255555520551515251055550522150110111050225150001000010520101510050100551115105050021501150105111155250101000101120001502520515015250002100510000000255000152552102110515501552552211120000101050505512152011001215150050222151501555520002010052552212125505000151050511100201055010205105050055502025522205000525100510001510215520550500505005051522502000151112251120222210501100552025005111510215500151125520211512102050512225550221125251200215210010001215512012521110111225155511151515105512550522010111151221101151225010510050155551211150112551250011102251115120555212502111255012515102505505121151551011052515252051201150011500150555501015150202115122151021205020501112155111110011210025522221102015551255505511555100512105005522510122005010052055200001205001055152221055500105111001222200222515220215150025502101210521022011510112021151551121050500551225120552511201055211101010000155551122101110501001052150055552250212050552255205255255552125252500512025011502525555155251002550010152510515151155550501550515011155050510510105120010522050201515012201515221555010505550002515520520051511201500205101120550500251005001555555011102210220155205050102010200255510501500201111155125525210525050222050111122115055251010522050105000220012225520125000512555212051215201011050051551255052155215100252201055010101100125111100500050115105500510555012212152121555512021005122101121222505012011521001001500521502120502522520121502250525050150250211555521505210551200000251120511100525510051125105000112001155115105521510205222025210250125200101005212002020511122010222110200515015521000022102152510225102051251250255221001515055000050112525251110520151012210105115511505025155051555051102120051252010150121001120552551205011125155155001155505151055511010022051551020500155055021000010051050512022011150110201502555251151210201501511221150551512050512251501001122102525215202500505155515011502151110105200205510520201150021520021100111005110210520002025215512215510500250101551525150125112555510015115155100520001020200202552155251255555255051502152055501002525511205225020550015552120505510552515552252105511101055255512115125515010501020100011250110255121550010105152122110220252555000012125521520015152121202100252015251501120552201050050002555525551102502255051151000000025512020010001025025050221110210050020121155112051051502010100252251250555011521210122221510110555515050012101110520505101115502020025051250550122105105515550120505501225051001051102001550511502500520100102500211511522150022152210515152201151021005015151005152500205512202010552155215215205520510021501210150011221152505220111121511512002502001152550001220055102155211201001210055550501115055021050522515505251122011055010222520522010501200521022552510522500200021000025202551122255152102501152055515250502502551521000252251505512225015115225120150251550500525511515021520020021525002155051120511022551101115115501550055200112220521210202055121525551522511050501501120110515102205100010515512511125000100150502012052000051021152051101555210511010110555015252020525155012522221122205111210250252051500520051015202522502155511501555020502555225025250205555511122520001055002021121000150015020510000025015021015221505552105121011252010501125111002205500100500225112152250210500001552220511052000515011012051512051000110212510125112101015555205105015522021210201052100110515105115015250015001015100025111111001552020512521500550055152001202222121152511105515115055052251250515155151055025520001205155150015000552001512055025111115021101000510221002502555212210200202025255215152015051205552550201055501015200052520501000115152552112501511025551252051011010005221052250000512522515011505115552555151120115500015001555555510222051502155500110100255200200105521500200510502510500150551155111201550155051151050115050151522122111212201020020502511525121201101505102025501521515200010512052510220121151201101025105511151155110515152105015520100125001212002521122155105025200055152002051121125520021522015112022011551052212020122051525552250010511512120050215152511200002122052555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555025555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555
```

The output is like this:

```
V1
1 Inf
2 Inf
3 Inf
4 Inf
5 Inf
6 Inf
```

And here is my standard read table function:

```
dna2 <- read.table(paste(path,"dna_new.txt",sep=""),
   header=FALSE)
```

Comment: Post a snippet of the input data that reproduces this issue. Cut down to as few lines and columns as necessary. Please use `dput()` not `print()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that R can only store numbers up to about 308 decimal digits long (and only about 16 digits of precision). So you should tell R to read these data as characters, not numbers.

Try setting the `colClasses=` argument:

```
dd <- read.table("SO_digits.txt",colClasses="character")
```

Alternatively you might want

```
scan("SO_digits.txt",what=character())
```

Comment: sentiment appreciated, but SO actually deprecates comments saying "thank you"; if it solves your problem, you can go ahead and click the check-mark (when SO lets you)

Comment: Sorry Ben, that's what I often do but I just forgot. Again, very appreciate you comments